# Deploying applications to a single instance in a glassfish cluster

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, cluster-computing

I have two Java EE applications that are able to talk to each others' remote interfaces via JNDI lookup.  I'd like to deploy both applications to a single glassfish domain but have them run on separate JVMs.  Is this setup possible?

Glassfish clusters seems to be the answer, however it doesn't look like I can control which instance gets which application -- it seems I have to deploy applications to the cluster itself which then pushes it out to all instances.

Answer (score 1):

Deploying to a single instance in a cluster is not possible. Oracle customer support answer:

*"I can confirm that what you are after is not possible. You cannot target a single instance if that instance is part of a cluster. That's what clusters are designed for and if you are not looking after cluster functionality, you can go with standalone instances."*

One possible solution could be to use the Domain Administration Server (DAS) for deployment of application A and the cluster for deployment of application B. But remember that you don't have High Availability (HA) for application A then. This is just a possible solution not my recommendation.